# How to increment a column using Eloquent Model in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am not sure how to increment the value in a column using Eloquent Model in Laravel 4?
This is what I currently have and I am not sure how correct is this.

```php
$visitor = Visitor::where('token','=','sometoken')->first();
if(isset($visitor)){
    $visitor->increment('totalvisits');
}else{
    Visitor::create(array(
    'token'=>'sometoken',
    'totalvisits'=>0
    ));
}
```

With Query Builder we could do it using

```php
DB::table('visitors')->increment('totalvisits');
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my end, is there anything more to it than what you've posted?

Comment: Should I call the save method after the increment method is called?

Comment: You don't need to with the 'increment' method since it's really intended to be used on a query where you wouldn't be saving afterwards. You could alternatively go $visitor->totalvisits = $visitor->totalvisits + 1; $visitor->save();

Comment: I don't think Eloquent's increment is atomic. So from the time you query for the visitor and then set it, it might have been changed by another visitor. So your visitor count will be lower than it should be.

Comment: @malhal I'm not sure if Laravel 4 was different but in 5.3, which I'm using right now, the `increment` method seems to be atomic:
`$columns = array_merge([$column => $this->raw("$wrapped + $amount")], $extra);`
`return $this->update($columns);`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like the code that I posted worked after all

```php
$visitor = Visitor::where('token','=','sometoken')->first();
if(isset($visitor)){
    $visitor->increment('totalvisits');
}else{
    Visitor::create(array(
    'token'=>'sometoken',
    'totalvisits'=>0
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Prior to a [fix a few weeks ago](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/eb1820899e882cf0cde9c255f55cdd9e94859edc) the `increment` method actually fell through to the query builder and would be called on the entire table, which was undesirable.

Now calling `increment` or `decrement` on a model instance will perform the operation only on that model instance.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I was not sure about how to use the incrememt method with an Eloquent Model and my code mentioned on the code works well. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5 now has atomic [increment](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php#L2244):

```
public function increment($column, $amount = 1, array $extra = [])
{
    if (! is_numeric($amount)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Non-numeric value passed to increment method.');
    }
    $wrapped = $this->grammar->wrap($column);
    $columns = array_merge([$column => $this->raw("$wrapped + $amount")], $extra);
    return $this->update($columns);
}
```

which essentially works like:

```
Customer::query()
->where('id', $customer_id)
->update([
'loyalty_points' => DB::raw('loyalty_points + 1')
]);
```

Below is old answer for Laravel 4 where the built-in increment was a seperate select and then update which of course leads to bugs with multiple users:

If you'd like to accurately count your visitors by ensuring the update is atomic then try putting this in your Visitor model:

```
public function incrementTotalVisits(){
    // increment regardless of the current value in this model.
    $this->where('id', $this->id)->update(['totalVisits' => DB::raw('last_insert_id(totalVisits + 1)')]);

    //update this model incase we would like to use it.
    $this->totalVisits = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

    //remove from dirty list to prevent any saves overwriting the newer database value.
    $this->syncOriginalAttribute('totalVisits');

    //return it because why not
    return $this->totalVisits;
}
```

I'm using it for a change tag system but might work for your needs too.

Does anyone know what to replace the "$this->where('id',$this->id)" with because since dealing with $this Visitor it should be redundant.

Comment: I left a reply to your other comment, but it seems like the Laravel version I'm using (5.3) implements an atomic `increment` method. Check out the [Illuminate query builder documentation](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php), the `increment` function is at line 2177.